# Estimate probability of event using moments of a distribution or a Taylor expansion involving the moments

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, moment-generating-functions

Let's say we have four moments $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3, \mu_4)$ of a probabilty distribution of a random variable $X$ and the goal is to get the probability $\rm{P}(X \leq t)$ for a certain value of $t$.

How is possible to use the moments to *approximate* such probabilty? Is there a way to use the moments in a Taylor expansion of the density?

Assume that $X$ has density which, at least, is four or five times differentiable, so the Taylor expansion makes sense.

Comment: I think you would have to start with a function that could be integrated over the range to give one. So a simple Taylor series would not do. It would be easy enough to think of modifications to standard PDFs which would give you enough free parameters yet still retain the essential ingredients of a PDF. Hopefully the moments may give you a clue to the pdf to start with.

Comment: Well, I can impose restrictions on the PDF and say that it can be integrated over the range. The Taylor expansion is just a **wild** idea. While is safe to assume continuity and derivability, I can olny use the four moments as parameters to _replace_ the PDF

Comment: Say start with $(1+ax+bx^2)N(\mu,\sigma)$. you need to fix up the normalisation. You can do all the integrations to find the moments and hopefully a and b will be small when you have fitted to the moments. There is probably smarter ways to do it, but it is a start.

Comment: Should I understand that idea as a suggestion to _reshape_ the normal distribution to something that match the four moments I have? I think you are right and that seems a good start. I'll let you know after I think in the math involved.

Comment: Here is the clever way of doing it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Stieltjes_inequalities. What I have suggested is not unique, you need to put bounds on P(X<=t) given the moments.

Comment: I'm trying to use the _reshaping_ idea, even if is not clever. I'm not sure that bounds helps in my [original problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658299/tranform-residual-to-match-expected-moments). I was hoping that getting the probability of a value under one set of moments I could get a quantile using a different set.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and just found this interesting private publication by S. Rabbani:

http://www.srabbani.com/moments2.pdf

Cut short, he constructs the PDF's Fourier transform as an infinite series over the PDF's moments. The inverse Fourier transform thus results in the PDF itself.

To get the cumulative distribution function (CDF), you could then try to find the PDF's antiderivative. The CDF's inverse function gives you the desired probability.

If I understand you correctly, then your given moments are already an approximation to the PDF for lack of higher moments. Had you given all moments, then I think the above would be accurate. Otherwise, user121049's link might give you upper bounds on your error.